# Changing The Font Of A JTextArea When Language Changes

Tags: java, user-interface

I am coding a simple java chat app. Is there any possibility of knowing the language user types in order to choose appropriate font?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Locale locale = InputContext.getLocale();
String language = locale.getLanguage();
```

But you must rely on the locale setting. I'm here on a German locale, but I'm happily typing English.